# navigation drawer back button stack bug

Tags: android, android-fragments, transactions, navigation-drawer, back-stack

i had an app with navigation drawer menu,
the problem is when i pressed the back button.

i have 2 menu on drawer = Fragment A, Fragment B
i go to the fragment A1, then go the A2, then i move to fragment B. then i press the back button on fragment B, the screen go back to fragment A.. i want if i press the back button on fragment B the app is close.
can anyone help me

this my code

Fragment A1

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("ZZZ", "ada di oncreateView maintain");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_schedule_day, container, false);
        final List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hm.put("day", days[i]);
            aList.add(hm);
            // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
            list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), aList, R.layout.list_schedule_day, new String[]{"day"}, new int[]{R.id.day});

            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    String day = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.day)).getText().toString();
//                    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),FragmentScheduleDetail.class);
//                    in.putExtra("txt",day);

                    Fragment fragment = new FragmentScheduleRoom();
                    Bundle data = new Bundle();
                    data.putString("selectday", day);
                    fragment.setArguments(data);
                    FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
                    Log.d("tag", "DAY SELECT: " + data.getString("selectday"));
                    FragmentTransaction tx = frgManager.beginTransaction();tx.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack( "schedule" ).commit();
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Clicked at " + aList.get(+position).get("day"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Fragment A2

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("ZZZ", "ada di oncreateView schedule");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_schedule_detail, container, false);
    new JSONParse().execute();
    return rootView;
}
```

Fragment B1

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_bad, container, false);
        new JSONParse().execute();

        return rootView;
    }



    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            device_id = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.device_id);
            name = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.name);
            location = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.location);
            status = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.status);
            device_type= (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.device_type);

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Bad Device List...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }



        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... string) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequestWithoutParams(url);
            Log.d("ZZZ", json.toString());
            return json;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            oslist.clear();
            try {
                // Getting JSON Array from URL
                String statusR = json.getString(TAG_STATUS);
                if(statusR.equals("success")){
                    bad = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
                    for(int i = 0; i < bad.length(); i++){
                        final JSONObject c = bad.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                        String device_id = c.getString(TAG_DEVICE_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String location = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                        String status = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);
                        String device_type = c.getString(TAG_DEVICE_TYPE);
                        // Adding value HashMap key => value
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put(TAG_DEVICE_ID, device_id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_LOCATION, location);
                        map.put(TAG_STATUS, status);
                        map.put(TAG_DEVICE_TYPE, device_type);
                        oslist.add(map);
                        list=(ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), oslist,
                                R.layout.list_bad,
                                new String[] {TAG_DEVICE_ID, TAG_NAME,TAG_LOCATION, TAG_STATUS, TAG_DEVICE_TYPE}, new int[] {
                                R.id.device_id, R.id.name, R.id.location, R.id.status, R.id.device_type});
                        list.setAdapter(adapter);
                        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                    int position, long id) {
                                String device_id = oslist.get(position).get("device_id");
                                String device_type = oslist.get(position).get("device_type");
                                Log.d("device_id", "IDP clicked : " + device_id);
                                Log.d("device_type", "Type clicked : " + device_type);

                                if (device_type.length()<7)
                                {
                                    Fragment fragment = new FragmentScanServer();
                                    Bundle data = new Bundle();
                                    data.putString("device_id", device_id);
                                    fragment.setArguments(data);
                                    FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
                                    Log.d("CLICK", "Send IDP to Maintenance Add : " + data.getString("device_id"));
//                                    frgManager.popBackStack("tag", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                                    frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                                            .commit();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Fragment fragment = new FragmentScanNetwork();
                                    Bundle data = new Bundle();
                                    data.putString("device_id", device_id);
                                    fragment.setArguments(data);
                                    FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
                                    Log.d("CLICK", "Send IDP to Maintenance Add : " + data.getString("device_id"));
                                    frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                                            .commit();
                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getBackStackEntryAt` to get top fragment from BackStack and check if user is on F2 fragment and back is pressed then close fragment container Activity. Override `onBackPressed()` method in Activity:

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
     FragmentManager fmanger = getSupportFragmentManager();
      if(fmanger.getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
      FragmentManager.BackStackEntry  backEntry=
                fmanger.getBackStackEntryAt(fmanger.getBackStackEntryCount()-1);
          String fragmentName=backEntry.getName();
          if(fragmentName.equals("schedule")){
                 // clear all fragment from Activity
                 // close Activity 
                 this.finish();
           }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some changes to the navigation logic to achieve this. So whenever you click any of the menu item you need to clear all the fragments in the stack and attach the new one.

The clear stack method is

```
private void clearStack() {    
    FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
    frgManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    frgManager.executePendingTransactions();
}
```

Thats it.